# I am looking to count the number of points in a certain region of my scatter plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom

I have a scatter plot:

```
ex<- ggplot(rdr, aes(x = hb, y = iv, color = pt))+ geom_point() + 
  ylim(-20,20) + 
  xlim(-20,20) +
  annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
           fill = "gray100", colour = "black", alpha = 0.5)  +
  annotate( geom = "rect", xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -15, ymax = -10, fill = "palegreen", color = "blue", alpha =0.5)
```

I want to count how many points are in each of the rectangles. And depending on the color of the point, I want to give them values. ex: blue(0), green(1).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the range for each variable in advance (which it seems like you do based on the `xmin` / `ymin` args you have), then I would do annotation *first*.

You don't have a scatterplot, you have data you are representing as a scatterplot, and you want to annotate the points so that they display as different colors on the scatterplot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
mtcars2 = mtcars %>%
  mutate(good = case_when(
    # this is the annotation step
    between(hp, 100, 150) & between(mpg, 15, 20) ~ 1,
    # this says everything else gets this value
    TRUE ~ 0
))
# we need as.factor to get different colors displayed
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.factor(good))) + geom_point()
```

[image]